# Add ListView into other ListView item

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to add a full custom Listview (with custom adapter) into an other custom ListView items.

I've tried two things :

1 : Using two custom ArrayAdapters and call the second one into the getView method of the first one. So each item gets populated with its own list. 
Result : It kinda works but I'm having problems to bind the right children list to the item inside getView and I thought I was probably doing an awful thing.

2: Using a expandableListView with its custom BaseExpandableListAdapter. It works better for binding parents/children items but I'm not able to put the children items into a specific listview inside the parent item. It just puts the children items after the entire parent item.

Is one of these methods supposed to work or can I use something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I think I just had desing problem. When you end up trying to nest ListViews, maybe the problem is just that what you are trying to do is not good.

It is true that I have an undefined number of elements that I want to display one below the other, which contains each a listview. But that doesn't mean that these elements should be wrapped into a listview. A simple for-loop to add each element to the Layout was a better option. Then, no problem with the lisview inside each element.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually use expandable list for that purpose, It has already 2 level though you can make it as much as you can.

You can customize parent and children, it'll better than adding element one by one manually.

I believe that's purpose of creation of expandable list.

Comment: Actually what I was trying to do is to wrap the children items in a specific layout of the parent item which is composed of multiple layouts. That is what I didn't manage to do. The expandable list just adds the children after its parent layout not inside in a specified element.

Comment: getChildView can be customized regarding to your taste, You can even put another expandable list or anything. You just need to create another list item for that purpose and inflate it. You can even make each child item different as well, but I might misunderstand your need.

Comment: I think you misunserstand. Example : The parent item is a vertical LinearLayout which contains two textViews then another linearLayout (id=childrenZone) then other stuff. I want the children of this item to appear inside the linearLayout with id=childrenZone. That way the whole children zone (not each single child item) can have things like a background, stuff before from parent and stuff after from parent. Is it clearer?